How do I force instantiation of the child class and not the parent class?
I have two modules, one.py:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def assign_A(self):
        self.A = A()

and two.py:
import one

class A(one.A):
    def bar(self):
        pass

class B(one.B):
    def foo():
        pass

b = B() 
b.assign_A()
b.A.bar()

I would like b.A to have access to the child class, two.A's, methods, but the code throws
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'bar',
because b makes use of the one.B.assign_A() method, which assigns an instance of one.A and not two.A Fair enough: assign_A() belongs to the parent, and one doesn't know anything about two.
I can think of a few solutions:

Move A.bar() into one
Duplicate the one.B.assign_A() method in two
Construct a function to convert b.A into an instance of two.A (maybe by copying its properties somehow).

I don't really like option 1, because bar() belongs conceptually to two. Option 2 duplicates code. And option 3 feels a bit messy. This makes me feel like my structure might be wrong.
Did I set things up poorly in the first place, and what is the most elegant solution to this problem?

I would go with option 2. This becomes more clear if two.A was simply named something else like C because what you're really doing is assigning C and not assigning A, so you can think of this either as an entirely new function or an overwritten function.

The natural O.O. mechanism that a child class has to have code defined in the superclasses to use derived attributes and methods, is to have that code (in the superclass) to use attributes, and then, override these attributes in the child.
For clarity, let's just do A, B, C classes in the same file - using the repeated name in the example where the name does not account for any changes won't help us:
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B:
    assignable = A
    def assign_A(self):
        self.A = type(self).assignable()

class C(A):
   def bar(...): ...

class D(B):
    assignable = C

As simple as this. No code needed in the most-derived classes. The inheritance mechanisms naturally will override the class attribute containing the class that should be instantiated in the D child, and you don't have to pass it explicitly, no chance of passing the incorrect class, etc...

A module should not depend on names defined in the importing module.
Instead, you should pass two.A to one.B as a parameter, then it can be called.
one.py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, a_class=A):
        self.a_class = a_class

    def assign_A(self):
        self.A = (self.a_class)()

two.py
import one

class A(one.A):
    def bar(self):
        pass

class B(one.B):
    def foo():
        pass

b = B(a_class=A) 
b.assign_A()
b.A.bar()


Thanks, that's quite nice (though I may pass the class directly to assign_A() rather than save it as a property). One question: why do you add __init__ methods to two?

Actually, it's not needed. The subclasses can simply inherit the base class methods.
